# How to install some extension to chrome broswer when load unpack option is disbaled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firewall

I am trying to install [Resurrectio](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Resurrectio?hl=en-US) extension to chrome broswer. I cannot directly install the plugin directly as I am behind the fire-wall. I found this [github](https://github.com/ebrehault/resurrectio) page for resurrectio which tells you to :

in Chrome:

- go to Tools / Extensions,
- expand Developer mode,
- click Load unpacked extension,
- select the ./resurrectio folder.

problem is, for me **Load unpacked extension** button is disbaled. Is there  hacky way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It would be unwise to try and circumvent enterprise policy lockdown in a *"hacky"* way if you value your job.

For a properly secured enterprise install (and probably not even local admin rights), there's nothing you can do.

What you *should* do is explain to your IT department why you need this. They will be able to override this for you.